# Match specific text only - jQuery string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the below code to change a class name of a button. However, I only want to do this for one button with the text 'Upload' and not another button that says 'Upload Database'.

Is it possible to change this from a 'Contains' to an exact match only?

```
<script>


$( ".sitebutton:contains('Upload')"   ).addClass('siteButton2').removeClass('sitebutton');


</script>
```

Comment: There is no way to target it without using the text? Basically you would need to use filter since there is no way to do an exact match

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this with `:contains` as it's a 'hungry' match. An alternative is to use `filter()`, where you can do an exact match:

```
$('.sitebutton').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() == 'Upload';
}).toggleClass('siteButton2 sitebutton');
```

If possible, a much better solution would be to just put an `id` or `class` on the required `button` element and select via that.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a jQuery filter on the elements:

```
$('.sidebutton')
    .filter((i, e) => $(e).text() === 'Upload')
    .addClass('sideButton2')
    .removeClass('sideButton');
```

You might need to trim the text, as there could be some extra whitespace floating around.

Comment: `e` would be the element, as there is no event firing in this context.

Comment: e is his second argument to filter method

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()` to check the `.textContent` of the element, `:contains()` checks if the text is included within the `.textContent` or `.innerText` in any form by using `.indexOf()` internally

```
$(".sitebutton").filter(function(i, el) {
  return el.textContent === "Upload"
})
.removeClass('sitebutton')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're generally making it harder on yourself, but you can do something like this:

```
$(".sitebutton.Upload").not(".Database").addClass('siteButton2').removeClass('sitebutton');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put a specific id for the button and then call the needed code to change the class.
Check this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/GxXxe11tAYGT7MH5ovaD)

This is the code
HTML:

```
 <input type=button id="upload" value="Upload" class="sitebutton">
 <input type=button id="uploaddb" value="Upload Database" class="sitebutton">
```

Script

```
 $('#upload').click(function() {
 $('#upload').addClass('siteButton2').removeClass('sitebutton');
 });
```